# Async await vs browser.wait approach difference

Tags: angular, protractor

Good morning,
I have started refactoring tests cases in Protractor (Angular app). I found that test cases should be written with `async await` approach but also I tried `browser.wait` which I assume is equivalent of the mentioned approach. Is this right? Below I add code examples.

```
async function (msg) {
  await main.getMessagesFromConversation()
    .then((bodyMessage) => expect(bodyMessage).to.equal(msg));
}
```

and the same with browser.wait

```
function (msg) {
  return browser.wait(main.getMessagesFromConversation()
    .then((bodyMessage) => expect(bodyMessage).to.equal(msg)), 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No `async/await` is not the same as `browser.wait`.

**Async/await** is a javascript style of handling promises. All browser interactions (and many other functions) within the protractor framework are wrapped in promises behind the scenes. This is due to the fact that webdriverJS, which Protractor relies on, is entirely asynchronous. Protractor uses promises to allow the code to be executed in the sequence it is written more easily.

Originally webdriverJS provided a feature called the control flow which allowed for all these promises to be handled behind the scenes. Since webdriverJS version 4 (I believe) this is deprecated and from protractor version 6.0+ protractor is now using webdriverJS 4 so the control flow it is also deprecated within protractor. `Async/await` is an easier and much more straight forward way to handle these promises.

Within Protractor `async/await` can be used as a alternative to `.then.catch()`. So for your example you would simply write instead:

```
async function (msg) {
  let conversationMsgs = await main.getMessagesFromConversation()
  expect(conversationMsgs).to.equal(msg));
}
```

**[browser.wait](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait)** is a command which pauses the execution until a particular promise or condition is resolved or reaches the timeout period. It is typically used to wait for elements to be present on a page but can have many other uses also.